# Href not working in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, href

I don't have a lot of experience in dealing with asp.net.  I have one line of code and I can't figure out why it isn't opening a css modal window which is linked by an href.  This is the line of code:

```
<div class="image-delete" id="dislikeListingButton" data-mls="@update.Number" data-searchid="@update.SearchId">
    <a href="#delete">
        <img src="/Content/img/delete.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

I can't figure out why the href surrounding the img doesn't trigger the modal window.

Comment: Where do you set the code that binds the `<a>` element to open the modal window? `href="#delete"` just makes it a link to another element (with `id="delete"`) on the same page.

Comment: The modal window is #delete which is located on the bottom of the page, but for some reason it doesn't work.  I can type in the id at the end of the url and it pulls up fine.  There is something in the a href that isn't letting the modal window trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming there is a div with an id of `delete` on your page.

You can scroll into view the `delete` div on clicking the href. Also, if that div was set with CSS of `display:none` then you could also set it to this CSS `display:block` so its visible and call the JavaScript method `scrollIntoView` to view it.

You can see a demo of similar code at this URL: [Demo Code](http://js.do/sun21170/79176). This demo is more sophisticated than code below in that it will toggle the delete div i.e. show on click of href and then hide on second click of href.

```
<div class="image-delete" id="dislikeListingButton" data-mls="@update.MLSNumber" 

    data-searchid="@update.SearchId">
        <a href="#" onclick="ShowPopup(); return false;">
            Open Window
        </a>
</div>

<scrip type="text/javascript">
  function ShowPopup() {
    //if div was not visible before you could also use the line below
    //document.getElementById("delete").style.display =  "block";
    document.getElementById("delete").scrollIntoView(true);
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

TRT THIS:$('#dislikeListingButton').click(function(){$('#delete').show()});